# git log --pretty=%P -n 1 <child> does not work on GitPython

Tags: gitpython

Does anyone know how I can make this work on GitPython?

`REPO.git.log('--pretty=%P -n 1 202bfa07e1fbaf7d210468a2ca6c7f4352fc2b25')`
puts it into an infinite loop.